# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration, farm-admin, internal-server-error

Unexpectedly when I open the the sharepoint web application I encountered the error **"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error"** .

May I know what's the issue and how can I solve it

Comment: Try to check memory usage. How many App pool running on the server ?

Comment: @MSA check this https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/28/500-internal-server-error-in-sharepoint-2013/ and please feedback me if worked or not

Comment: @MSA, You need to check 3 places on the server to identify this issue. 1) Event Viewer. 2) IIS log files. 3) ULS logs. Please update your question if you find more detail about the error.